How to copy found data to a specified range across multiple sheets?
My code will read row 1, find a specific criteria, set that column it finds it in as a searchable range, find a specific name (rs.Name) in that row, offset to the 4 columns next to it and copy that data.
I need after copying, to the paste that data on the corresponding sheet (rs.Name) in a specified range (PasteRange).
I have everything except the paste. I confirmed it will copy.
I get

Object doesn't support this property or method

My only thought is that I'm setting the range too far ahead of time for it to paste. But I need it to do it before the loop so that I don't have to specify the range for every sheet. (There's 28 of them.)
I've looked at some examples of using .copy destination and it looks to me that I did it correctly.
There may be superfluous variables. I plan to clean that up afterwards.
Function WorksheetExists(WSName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = Worksheets(WSName).Name = WSName
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Sub FindData()

Dim shname As String
Dim rs As Worksheet
Dim SampleEnding As String
Dim rFind As Range, cFind As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wk As Workbook
Dim SampleLook As Range
Dim SampleFind As Range
Dim SampleFind2 As Range
Dim PasteRange As Range
Dim Name As String

Set wk = ThisWorkbook
Set PasteRange = Application.InputBox("What is the range you will be copying to? Ex. E2:H2", Type:=8)

Do Until WorksheetExists(shname)
shname = InputBox("Enter sheet name")

If StrPtr(shname) = 0 Then
MsgBox ("User Cancelled!")
Exit Sub

Else
If Not WorksheetExists(shname) Then MsgBox shname & " doesn't exist!", vbExclamation

End If

Loop

SampleEnding = Application.InputBox("What is the string of the data file you are using? Ex: *_1.D,* or *_2.D", Type:=2)

Set rFind = wk.Sheets(shname).Rows("1:1").Find(What:=SampleEnding, After:=wk.Sheets(shname).Range("XFD1"), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If rFind Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Value not found"
Else
    Debug.Print rFind.Column
    cFind = Split(wk.Sheets(shname).Cells(1, rFind.Column).Address(True, False), "$")(0)
    
End If

For Each rs In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   If rs.Name = "hexafluoroethane" Or rs.Name = "chlorotrifluoromethane" Or _
   rs.Name = "Trifluoromethane" Or rs.Name = "Octafluoropropane" Or rs.Name = "Difluoromethane" Or _
   rs.Name = "Pentafluoroethane" Or rs.Name = "Octafluorocyclobutane" Or rs.Name = "Fluoromethane" Or _
   rs.Name = "Tetrafluoroethylene" Or rs.Name = "Hexafluoropropene" Or rs.Name = "Trifluoroethane" _
   Or rs.Name = "hexafluoropropene oxide" Or rs.Name = "chlorodifluoromethane" Or rs.Name = "Tetrafluoroethane" Or rs.Name = "Decafluorobutane" _
   Or rs.Name = "Heptafluoropropane" Or rs.Name = "Octafluorocyclopentene" Or rs.Name = "Trichlorofluoromethane" Or rs.Name = "Dodecafluoro-n-pentane" _
   Or rs.Name = "Nonafluorobutane" Or rs.Name = "Tetradecafluorohexane" Or rs.Name = "Undecafluoropentane" Or rs.Name = "E1" _
   Or rs.Name = "Hexadecafluoroheptane" Or rs.Name = "Tridecafluorohexane" Or rs.Name = "Perfluorooctane" Or rs.Name = "Pentadecafluoroheptane" _
   Or rs.Name = "Heptadecafluorooctane" Or rs.Name = "E2" Then

Set SampleFind = Range(cFind & "6:" & cFind & "34").Find(rs.Name, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not SampleFind Is Nothing Then
        Set SampleFind2 = Range(SampleFind.Offset(0, 1), SampleFind.Offset(0, 4))
            If Not SampleFind2 Is Nothing Then
                wk.Sheets(shname).SampleFind2.Copy Destination:=wk.Sheets(rs.Name).PasteRange
            End If
    End If
    
End If

Next rs

End Sub


I suspect that the PasteRange size/shape is different than the range you've copied. Can you check that? Also, if your user can type in a range (and therefore enter an "illegal" size/shape range) you should check that and force it to be correct.

Double checked and the sizing is the same. It's a 1 row by 4 column selection for PasteRange and then I'm copying a 1 row by 4 column area for SampleFind2.


Below code doesn't work. Sheets(..).<rangeobject> is not a right approach. Based your code, I think you can use wk.Sheets(rs.Name).Range(PasteRange.Address).

wk.Sheets(shname).SampleFind2.Copy Destination:=wk.Sheets(rs.Name).PasteRange


It's important to qualify the Range object with the Sheet to avoid any ambiguity. By default, the Range object refers to the ActiveSheet if the code is in a standard module.

    Set SampleFind = wk.Sheets(shname).Range(cFind & "6:" & cFind & "34").Find(rs.Name, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not SampleFind Is Nothing Then
        Set SampleFind2 = Range(SampleFind.Offset(0, 1), SampleFind.Offset(0, 4))
        If Not SampleFind2 Is Nothing Then
            If SampleFind2.Count = PasteRange.Count Or PasteRange.Count = 1 Then
                SampleFind2.Copy Destination:=wk.Sheets(rs.Name).Range(PasteRange.Address)
            End If
        End If
    End If


You are an absolute wizard and genius thank you so so much! I knew I was missing something obvious!

@Taller has the correct answer (and beat me to it).
As a bonus and FYI - in VBA when you have an If statement with multiple conditions, each condition is evaluated, even if the first condition is met. So you may want to consider the function below:
Sub test()
    Debug.Print ChemNameInList("ddd")
    Debug.Print ChemNameInList("Difluoromethane")
End Sub

Function ChemNameInList(rsName As String) As Boolean
    Dim chemNames() As String
    chemNames = Split("hexafluoroethane,chlorotrifluoromethane,Trifluoromethane," & _
                      "Octafluoropropane,Difluoromethane,Pentafluoroethane," & _
                      "Octafluorocyclobutane,Fluoromethane,more chemicals", ",")
    Dim chem As Variant
    ChemNameInList = False
    For Each chem In chemNames
        If chem = rsName Then
            ChemNameInList = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next chem
End Function

